# Is it possible to remove this action? (as it's added just before it's called)

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions

In wp-signup.php there are these lines:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpmu_signup_stylesheet' );
get_header();
```

I need to remove `wpmu_signup_stylesheet` from the `wp_head` action, but I seem to be struggling, I assume it is because the action is being called straight after.

Here is what I've tried from a plugin:

```
// Called from an action that is added with:
// add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'remove_signup_style', 11));
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wpmu_signup_stylesheet');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action is not right after actually. There is `get_header()` call, then `get_header` action and then locating and loading template file that has `wp_head()` in it.

I try not to mess with removing things from inside of same hook you are at, so in this case I'd (ab)use that `get_header` action to hook function that will remove what you don't want from later `wp_head`.

Comment: Many thanks, just changed the hook of the function that called `remove_action` to `get_header`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip @Rarst! Working code below.

```
//Remove the css injected into wp_head for the wp-signup.php form
add_action('get_header', 'remove_wpmu_signup_styles');
function remove_wpmu_signup_styles () {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wpmu_signup_stylesheet');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a priority:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wpmu_signup_stylesheet', 11 );
```

p.s. is the `add_action()` call really placed before `get_header()`, or is it placed before `wp_head()`? I'm not sure it really matters, so long as `wp_head()` is included in `header.php`; but that's just an unusual place to add an `add_action()` call.

Comment: The priority arg passed to remove_action() has to match the one from add_action().

Comment: I always seem to forget that! :)

Comment: Yeah those two lines are exactly as that in wp-signup.php. As per the docs you can only remove an action if the priorty is the same, the weird thing is that remove_Action actually returns true yet the action is still being ran.